# Illustrator Grain Texture SVG file size

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, export, illustrator-effects, file-size

Is there a way to reduce a file size svg with grain texture effect? I'm doing a website illustration in svg format and after the export, the file is around 50mb+. Without the grain effect is around 50kb. What I can do keep it small and maintaining the grain effect? Is it possible to do the same effect with lower size impact?

Comment: Which grain version is used? Some grains are actually raster image overlays which in high resolution can be tens of megabytes. But he raster overlay should be a linked PNG file. Have you it? Vector grain can be effectively inserted or dumb. The latter version has every grain as a separate vector shape - do not expect it's compact! Native SVG filters can keep the file size small. Make a version which has only one object with grain and read what's included. Open the file in a text editor for it. If the file is originally yours you can tell in the question what the grain exactly is.

Comment: Rethink the grain... pull it off with vectors rather than the (default) raster image.